# Efficient way to create a diagonal sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have the following code in Python using Numpy:

```
p = np.diag(1.0 / np.array(x))
```

How can I transform it to get the sparse matrix `p2` with the same values as `p` without creating `p` first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`scipy.sparse.spdiags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spdiags.html#scipy.sparse.spdiags) (which does a lot, and so may be confusing, at first), [`scipy.sparse.dia_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.dia_matrix) and/or [`scipy.sparse.lil_diags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.identity.html#scipy.sparse.identity). (depending on the [format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#sparse-matrix-classes) you want the sparse matrix in...)

E.g. using `spdiags`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse

x = np.arange(10)

# "0" here indicates the main diagonal...
# "y" will be a dia_matrix type of sparse array, by default
y = sp.sparse.spdiags(x, 0, x.size, x.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the scipy.sparse module,

```
p = sparse.dia_matrix(1.0 / np.array(x), shape=(len(x), len(x)));
```